# What's this mean: "The search for Assistant Professor, Mathematics has been suspended. Please visit the X University website for future openings."

Tags: job-search, faculty-application

What's this mean: “The search for Assistant Professor, Mathematics has been suspended. Please visit the X University website for future openings.”

I got an email from HR saying the search has been suspended.  I am not sure what they mean by that.  Did I fail the initial screening, or did they just lost funding for the position?, or else??

Comment: It probably means that they are no longer looking, for whatever reason

Comment: "we don't have any money left"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This means that the entire search has been placed "on hold" or even cancelled.  This does not indicate any judgment on your abilities or suitability for the position, but instead reflects internal problems (for instance, funding challenges or a change in direction). It may also indicate that there were no suitable candidates found, or not enough applications were received.

Comment: @OswaldVeblen: If that were the case, one would expect to see "temporarily" or some indication of when the suspension would end.

Comment: Frankly it could even mean that they hired a candidate. They're just wording it in a nice way so that you hopefully come back.

Comment: @aeismail Given the vagaries of funding and departmental politics, I actively *wouldn't* mention an end date for the suspension.